# Accesing AsyncTask form adapter class (non activity class)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I created AsyncTask in my Activity class it is working fine.My question is I have to access the same AsyncTask from adapter class how can i do this.Please provide any solutions.
 Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible, but you can try making the AsyncTask a public static variable, then you can use this in your Adapter but I don't know if this will work correctly

Comment: You have defined a private AsyncTask class in your activity and you want to initialize and use it in your adapter?

Comment: Hi Nickolaus,I tried this but doesn't work

Comment: Hi Amit could you provide any example..

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class for your AsyncTask like below

File: DownloadFilesTask.java

```
public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
          ---
          ---
     }
}
```

In your activity, initialize object of your AsyncTask and execute it if required. You can do the same in your adapter class.

Please note that, according to threading rules, The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread and The task instance must be created on the UI thread. To work around this, just initialize object of AsyncTask on your activity's onCreate method (whether you are planning to use it in your activity or not, but it is necessary to create an object of AsyncTask if you want to use it outside your activity)